# Avoiding Redundancy using LINQ Enumerable All

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, redundancy

I often feel that the `IEnumerable<T>.All` method is redundant when your `T` is a boolean array.

Given the following sample code, is there a better way to validate to use the All method

```cs
bool isOrdered = firstList
     .Zip(secondList, (first,second)=>first==second)
     .All(areSame => areSame); /* feels redundant */
```

In some other languages, just calling `.All()` ensures all elements are true.  Is something like this possible in c# without the akward `.All(x=>x)`

Comment: You can wrote your own extension methods named AllTrue and AllFalse

Comment: Maybe write your own extension for `IEnumerable<bool>` called `AllTrue` (or whatever) and call there `All(x=>x)` ? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid predicate in `All` operator. It is part of signature, and it is not optional:

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

What you can do is create your own `All` (or better `AllTrue`) extension specific to collection of booleans:

```
public static bool AllTrue(this IEnumerable<bool> source)
{
    return source.All(b => b);
}

public static bool AllFalse(this IEnumerable<bool> source)
{
    return source.All(b => !b);
}
```

Usage:

```
bool isOrdered = firstList
     .Zip(secondList, (first,second) => first == second)
     .AllTrue();
```